# Removing element from arraylist not showing consistent behavior

Tags: java, arraylist

I am implementing a game where there are falling objects. They are stored in an `ArrayList` and when they hit the ground, I want to remove them from the arraylist.

I am doing this like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fo_ArrayList.size(); i++) {
    if (fo_ArrayList.get(i).hasHitGround()) {
        fo_ArrayList.remove(i);
    }
}
```

I have another thread that is accessing this arraylist and using its size. The problem is, sometimes my game crashes, and sometimes it doesnt. Why is it not consistent? And what is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: If it crashes, with what exception? Also, your loop will skip elements if you remove stuff.

Comment: Every now and then I get index out of bounds because the size of the arraylist is not what i am expecting it to be.

Comment: 1. Use iterators to remove objects during iteration. 2. use synchronization to lock objects shared between threads

Comment: @Lashane I've been reading about synchronization but how exactly do I use it? do I just say `synchronized(this) { // arraylist code }` in both of my threads?

Comment: 1. do not use this in synchronized blocks. 2. read more, it is big and complex topic

Comment: Additionally, if you're doing a *lot* of removals, ArrayList might not be the data structure you are looking for.

Comment: @MattCoubrough I'm doing about 1 removal a second. Is that a lot? It takes a second for an object to fall

Comment: If you are not experiencing performance issues then you probably don't need to worry: When you remove an item from the middle of an ArrayList everything after that is moved up one index, which can be slow if you have a *lot* of elements in your List (ie 1000s). The important thing is to understand the strengths and weaknesses of different data structures for your particular use-cases. If you're not finding any performance problems, ArrayList should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to remove elements from an ArrayList while iterating over it, you should use an Iterator. (Replace Object with the type stored in the ArrayList)

```
Iterator<Object> iterator = fo_ArrayList.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  if(iterator.next().hasHitGround()) {
    iterator.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey this works! Thanks a lot. Why does this work though?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html, the Iterator class ensures that removals from a collection while iterating over it are well defined.